# \underbrace and notes in the center environment

Tags: formatting, notes

Here is a little snippet of my code:

```
\begin{center}
$\small \displaystyle \underbrace{(- \frac{1}{2})^0}_{\text{1st term, j = 0}} +
\underbrace{(- \frac{1}{2})^1}_{\text{2nd term, j = 1}} + \underbrace{(- \frac{1}{2})^2}_
{\text{3rd term, j = 2}} + ~...+ \underbrace{(- \frac{1}{2})^k}_{\text{kth term, 2nd to \linebreak last term, j = k}} + \underbrace{(- \frac{1}{2})^{k+1}}_{\text{(k+1)th term,
 last in the sum}}$  
\end{center}
```

and this is the output

[image]

I would like this to be on one line, but have the notes underneath the last two terms split into two. How might I do this?

Comment: So do you want two lines in the notes below the fractions? Not two lines for the whole expression? Also, use `\[ \]` to center a math expression.

Comment: I would like to two lines in the notes below the fractions. How does using \[ \] compare to using center? What would I have to change?

Comment: @Mack Don't use `center` for displaying equations, but `\[...\]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this differs only slightly from the answer by Sigur, but i think it's worth some small adjustments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\small
\[
 \displaystyle
 \underbrace{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^0}_{\substack{\text{1st term,}\\ j = 0}}
 + \underbrace{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^1}_{\substack{\text{2nd term,}\\ j = 1}}
 + \underbrace{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}
   _{\substack{\text{3rd term,}\\ j = 2}}
 + \ \cdots\ 
 + \underbrace{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k}
   _{\substack{\text{\ \ $k$th term,\ \ }\\ \mathclap{\text{2nd to last term,}}\\ j = k}}
 + \underbrace{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k+1\mkern-20mu}}
   _{\substack{\text{$(k{+}1)$th term,}\\ \text{ last in the sum }}}
\]
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

here are the differences:

- to narrow the next-to-last term (thus reducing the space around  the final plus),
  the widest line in the substack was "compressed" using `\mathclap` (requires
  `mathtools`), and spaces were added to the first line to adjust so that the notations
  on the last two terms don't overlap.  (shortening this phrase is probably a better
  approach, actually, but that might not always be feasible.)
- negative space was added to the end of the superscript on the last term, allowing
  it to hang over the brace, resulting in a brace closer in size to the others.
- space was added (inside the `\text`) to the second line of the substack on the last
  term to further improve the spacing between the last two terms.
- in the first line of the notation on the last term, braces were put around the `{+}`
  so that the spacing within `k+1` is optically comparable to the spacing in the
  superscript.  (it should probably be `$(k+1)st`, but let's not quibble.)

egreg's use of a macro refinement in Sigur's answer is a good idea that would work
here too.

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by @egreg, using `\substack{}` you can insert multiple lines. Also, the font size is automatically adjusted.

Note some extra spaces `\ \`around the `\cdots` (requested by @Thruston).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[   
\underbrace{\left( -\frac{1}{2}\right)^0}_{\substack{
\text{1st term,}\\ j = 0}} + 
\underbrace{\left( -\frac{1}{2}\right)^1}_{\substack{\text{2nd term,}\\ j = 1}} + 
\underbrace{\left( -\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}_{\substack{\text{3rd term,}\\ j = 2}} 
+ \ \cdots \ + 
\underbrace{\left( -\frac{1}{2}\right)^k}_{\substack{\text{$k$th term,}\\ \text{2nd to last term,}\\ j = k} } + 
\underbrace{\left( -\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k+1}}_{\substack{\text{$(k+1)$th term,}\\ \text{last in the sum}} }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

A refinement for using less keystrokes and minimize the chance of errors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
% Define a shortcut macro just for this display;
% use \left and \right instead of \Bigl and \Bigr
% if you feel these are too small
\newcommand{\myterm}[2]{%
  \underbrace{\Bigl(-\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)^{#1}}_{\substack{#2}}%
}
\myterm{0}{\text{1st term,} \\ j=0}+
\myterm{1}{\text{2nd term,} \\ j=1}+
\myterm{2}{\text{3rd term,} \\ j=2}+
\;\cdots\;+ % some space around the dots
\myterm{k}{\text{$k$th term,} \\ \text{2nd to last,} \\ j=k}+
\myterm{k+1}{\text{$(k+1)$th term,} \\ \text{last in the sum}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd use `\substack` (with `\text` inside) instead of a `tabular`

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. Thank you, Sigur.

Comment: @egreg, well remembered. I'll edit with your suggestion.

Comment: @Sigur and some extra space around the `cdots`?

Comment: @Thruston, I agree. The problem is spaces around other pluses. It is difficulty to decide what to use :-)

Comment: @Mack, I edited to follow the suggestions. Please, copy again.

Comment: @Sigur I added a possibly better solution; it's basically the same as yours, the local macro avoids many keystrokes.

Comment: @Sigur What typo? ;-)

Comment: Not anymore. You're fast.