# How to make two line apex

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I'd like to split the apex in two lines. I'm commenting a part of an equation with `\overbrace` and I need to split the comment in two line because it is too long.

```
$$ x = \overbrace{y}^{very big comment} $$
```

Comment: could be a job for `substack`?

Comment: That's great, I'm glad it works! :) I think there may be a duplicate somewhere round here that talks about `substack`- if I can't find it, I'll post an answer (assuming I'm not beaten to the punch)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151960/underbrace-and-notes-in-the-center-enviroment